# Libusb-1.0.9 ERROR Messages

Tags: assembly

Writing a Windows Based Program in Assembly Language  to use the Library. Windows XP Sevice Pack 3 32-bit Assembly. Cand get the include and lib files into the project to even compile correctly before I even call any of the functions in The library!

LINK : fatal error LNK1196: invalid or corrupt import object: unknown version So I have the source code to the library how to I get the linker to stop complaining about the error? 
I guess I need to know what I have to do in the Source code of the library to make it comply?
The library compiles correctly and I can use it in C or C++, but I am far more comfortable in Assembly Language, been doing it for 30+ years .
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you use markdown to format your question and make it a little clearer?

Answer (score 0):

To call a library routine from an assembly language routine in Windows VS environment, the following steps are required (examples are from VS 2015):

Step 1: in the assembly routine, please declare the function as below (example _sopen_s()):

extern     _sopen_s : proc     ; this is a library function

Step 2 : the Project environment must include that library which contains the function. For standard VS C/C++ libraries, this is done by Project->Linker->General->Link Library Dependencies set to "Yes"

If you have created your own libraries, then Project->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories should point to the directory where the additional libraries are located.

Now regarding includes, please observe that includes define certain flag values, so if you wish to use any specific flag value, you need to either "rewrite" it as

SEEK_CUR                            EQU     1           ; copied from stdio.h

or use directly, as below (example of a file create):

```
lea         rcx,dest_file_descriptor        ; int * fd
mov         rdx,r11                         ; filename * in R11
mov         r8,8000H                        ; set up the flag _O_BINARY (we handle all translations ourselves)
or          r8,100H                         ; or with _O_CREAT
or          r8,200H                         ; and further or with _O_TRUNC
or          r8,0002H                        ; and finally with _O_RDWR (fcntl.h)
mov         r9,040H                         ; set up the flag _SH_DENYNO (share.h)
mov         r10,0080H                       ; set up the flag _S_IWRITE (io.h)
or          r10,0100H                       ; or with _S_IREAD
sub         rsp,20H
push        r10                             ; _sopen_s(int * fd,char * filename, _O_BINARY | _O_CREAT | _O_TRUNC | _O_RDWR, _SH_DENYNO, _S_IWRITE)
call        _sopen_s
pop         r10
add         rsp,20H
```

Trust this helps... Its usually a frustrating start, in my experience, but soon will get sorted out...